# Changing textblock origin in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have a textblock placed at the point 250, 250 (X: 250, Y: 250). Using a dot as reference, I can see that the textblock is placed at the origin 0,0 (of the textblock). Is there anyway to change the origin to, say, the center of the textbox, or the lower right hand corner?

Comment: Origin of the text in the TextBlock?

Comment: Origin of the textblock itself (and in turn, the text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that [RenderTransformOrigin()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransformorigin.aspx) works quite well, especially if you need to change the origin because of a transform.

`textBlock.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);` will specify the origin in the middle .

From MSDN:

> RenderTransformOrigin has a somewhat nonstandard use of the Point structure value, in that the Point does not represent an absolute location in a coordinate system. Instead, values between 0 and 1 are interpreted as a factor for the range of the current element in each x,y axis. For example, (0.5,0.5) will cause the render transform to be centered on the element, or (1,1) would place the render transform at the bottom right corner of the element. NaN is not an accepted value.